# Cannot delete mac alias file

Tags: xcode, macos, alias, macos-sierra

I am having severe issue with mac alias. I have ana xcode project working fine except recently it denied to find a View controller class ("`A.swift`") to set in storyboard. Tried many tweaks with zero results. Finally I searched in finder in my main project directory for that view controller file name, and I found that I have some alias file as well for that view controller.

I cannot delete that alias, cannot locate the original file (no information in `Get Info`, `Select New Original...` is grayed).

[image]

Any help for this?

Note: I have two `A.swift` files for Mac OS and iOS, both in different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try with rollback/checkout you last changes if you haven't made big.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did, I just abandoned that entire directory, fresh pull my branch and that alias is not there.